# Proof infinite series $1 + 2 + 3 +\cdots +n+\cdots$ diverges

Tags: divergent-series

**Question:**

> By considering the partial sums for S, that is
>
> $S_n = 1 + 2 + 3 +\cdots +n$
>
> show that the infinite series S does not converge.

**My answer :**

I tried to attempt this question, but I was able to prove that the series converges to $-1/12$ instead of diverges. Can anyone help me to prove it diverges instead of converges? your help is appreciated.

Comment: What? It converges?

Comment: I proof that it converges , but the question want me to show that it diverges . I need help for that .Do I use the proofing of harmonic series ? if not can you tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: @ Solid Snake, I have not learn Cesàro summation , can you show me how you do it ? Cesaro summation is for the case of 1-1+1-1+1..... , but this is not the case are you sure about using that to solve this?

Comment: Direct calculation shows $1+2+\cdots + n = n(n+1)/2$. Can you calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(n+1)/2$?

Comment: this "converges" to $-\frac{1}{12}$ using an extension of $\zeta$ function. i don't know much about this but your serie do not converges

Comment: @tetori , if lim n→∞n(n+1)/2 diverges , the infinite series S diverges too ? is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, remind the definition of infinite series - infinite series $\sum_n a_n$ defined as the **limit** of finite series $\lim_N\sum_{n<N} a_n$.

Comment: I think we should say that this series diverge, but with black magic the sum is $-1/12$. You can find many questions about this on MSE (probably on MO as well, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument you're using to prove it "converges" to $-1/12$ is using a [different idea of summability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), here, you're being asked to prove it diverges in the common sense: you must prove the sequence $\{S_n\}_n$ diverges.

This is an easy task since for all $n\in \Bbb N:$

$$|S_n|=S_n=1+2+\cdots +n\geq n\ \ .$$

Comment: My answer:

S0 = 1
S1 = 1 + 2 = 3
S2 = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7
S3 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15                

So we see that Sn → ∞ meaning that the sum diverges.

Please forgive me for my incorrect way of commenting in this website . Does my answer utilize your explanation ? Is it correct ?

Comment: Your argument is fine, lacks of rigurosity but it shows what's going on. A more formal proof would go as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Ok thx for the big help , appreciated . :D

Answer (score 1):

For a serie to convergence, one must have
$$\mid s_{n+1}-s_n\mid\rightarrow 0$$
but in this case this is equivalent to $n\rightarrow 0$. Clearly, this is not the case as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

A Serie diverges if for all $A\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such $S_{n_0}>A$

set $n_0=A$.

also, if it is convergent, then it should be bounded. ;)